# Calculating $\int_A \frac{z}{y^2}$ with $A:=\{z\ge0,x\ge1,y\ge 0, x^2+z^2<\min(2x,y^2)\}$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals, solution-verification, multiple-integral

I want to calculate the following improper integral:

$$\int_A \frac{z}{y^2}\\
A:=\{z\ge0,x\ge1,y\ge 0, x^2+z^2<\min(2x,y^2)\}$$

First I noticed that the conditions imply $x^2<2x\rightarrow x<2;1<x^2<y^2\rightarrow y>1$, and thus $B=A\cap \{y>2\}=\{z\in(0,2),x\in(1,2), x^2+z^2<2x\}$. Thus this part of the integral is fairly easy:

$$\int_B\frac{z}{y^2}=\int_2^\infty\int_1^2\int_0^\sqrt{2x-x^2}\frac{z}{y^2}dzdxdy=\int_2^\infty\frac1{y^2}dy\int_1^2\frac{2x-x^2}{2}dx=\frac{1}{6}$$

We are now left with a "proper" integral (i.e. the region on which we are integration is finite, and the integrand is bounded):

$$\int_{A\cap\{y\in(1,2)\}}\frac{z}{y^2}$$

I tried to split the domain in two regions: $A'=\{x\in[1,2);y\in(x,\sqrt{2x});z\in [0,\sqrt{y^2-x^2})\}, A''=\{x\in[1,2);y\in[\sqrt{2x},2];z\in[0,\sqrt{2x-x^2})$

Is my approach correct (I'm not sure, since the computations that follow bring me to an uncorrect result)? Is there any other approach to computing this integral, perhaps less messy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can partition the domain $A$ into regions $A_1,A_2,A_3$ . . .

The diagram below shows the projections of $A_1,A_2,A_3$ onto the $xy$-plane.

[image]

Region $A_1$ is defined by
$$
\left\lbrace
\begin{align*}
0\le\,&z\le \sqrt{y^2-x^2}\\[4pt]
x\le\,&y\le\sqrt{2x}\\[4pt]
1\le\,&x\le 2\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
\right.
$$
so letting $a_1$ denote the integral for region $A_1$, we get
\begin{align*}
a_1&=\int_1^2\int_x^{\sqrt{2x}}\int_0^{\sqrt{y^2-x^2}}\!\frac{z}{y^2}\;dz\,dy\,dx\\[4pt]
&=\frac{19-13\sqrt{2}}{30}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Region $A_2$ is defined by
$$
\left\lbrace
\begin{align*}
0\le\,&z\le \sqrt{2x-x^2}\\[4pt]
1\le\,&x\le\frac{y^2}{2}\\[4pt]
\sqrt{2}\le\,&y\le 2\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
\right.
$$
so letting $a_2$ denote the integral for region $A_2$, we get
\begin{align*}
a_2&=\int_\sqrt{2}^2\int_1^{\frac{y^2}{2}}\int_0^{\sqrt{2x-x^2}}\!\frac{z}{y^2}\;dz\,dx\,dy\\[4pt]
&=\frac{11-7\sqrt{2}}{30}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Region $A_3$ is defined by
$$
\left\lbrace
\begin{align*}
0\le\,&z\le \sqrt{2x-x^2}\\[4pt]
1\le\,&x\le 2\\[4pt]
2\le\,&y < \infty\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
\right.
$$
so letting $a_3$ denote the integral for region $A_3$, we get
\begin{align*}
a_3&=\int_2^\infty \int_1^2\int_0^{\sqrt{2x-x^2}}\!\frac{z}{y^2}\;dz\,dx\,dy\\[4pt]
&=\int_2^\infty\!\frac{1}{3y^2}\;dy\\[4pt]
&=\frac{1}{6}
\end{align*}
Combining the results, we get
$$
\int_{\Large{A}}\,\frac{z}{y^2}=a_1+a_2+a_3=\frac{7-4\sqrt{2}}{6}
$$

Comment: It seems to me that your regions $A_3=B;A_1=A'$,but I do not see how $A''=A_2$. Is it the case, or is my division wrong?

Comment: @JohnBLewis: Now that I've looked more carefully at your divisions, I see that they are, in fact, the same. My $A_2$ is the same as your $A''$, but I chose the order $dz\,dx\,dy$ and you chose the order $dz\,dy\,dx$. The evaluation should come out the same.

Answer (score 1):

The conditions $z\ge 0$, $x\ge 1$, $y\ge 0$, $x^2+z^2 \lt 2x$, and $x^2+z^2 \lt y^2$ define the intersection of two solids.  Solid one is the quarter of the cylinder $(x-1)^2 + z^2 = 1$ to the right of the plane $x=1$ and above the plane $z=0$.  Solid two is the portion of the cone $x^2 + z^2 = y^2$ to the right of the plane $x=1$ and above the plane $z=0$.  For $y\ge 2$, the cone completely contains the cylinder, so $A$ is just the cylinder in this portion of $A$.  The integral is indeed $1/6$ over this subregion $A_1$.

You can split the remainder of $A$ into two subregions $A_2$ and $A_3$.  The first is the subregion where the boundary of the cone is intersecting the slice of the plane $x=1$ between $z=0$ and $z=1$.  The second is the subregion where the boundary of the cone is intersecting the upper boundary of the cylinder between $x=1$ and $x=2$.  The integral over $A_2$ is
$$
  \begin{align}
  \int_{A_2} z/y^2 &= \int_1^{\sqrt{2}} \frac{1}{y^2} \int_0^{\sqrt{y^2-1}} z 
     \int_1^{\sqrt{y^2-z^2}} \,dx\,dz\,dy \\
  &= \int_1^{\sqrt{2}}\frac{1}{y^2}\int_0^{\sqrt{y^2-1}} (z\sqrt{y^2-z^2} - z) \, dz\, dy \\
  &= \int_1^{\sqrt{2}} \frac{1}{y^2} \left.\left(-(y^2-z^2)^{3/2}/3 - z^2/2\right)
     \right|_{z=0}^{z=\sqrt{y^2-1}} \,dy \\
  &= \int_1^{\sqrt{2}} \frac{1}{y^2}\left(\frac{1}{6} - \frac{y^2}{2} + \frac{y^3}{3}\right) \,dy \\
  &= \left. -\frac{1}{6y} - \frac{y}{2} + \frac{y^2}{6}\right|_1^{\sqrt{2}} \\
  &= \frac{5}{6} - \frac{7}{12}\sqrt{2}.
  \end{align}
$$

The integral over $A_3$ is
$$
  \int_{A_3} z/y^2 = \int_{\sqrt{2}}^{2}\frac{1}{y^2}\int_0^1 z 
    \int_1^{\min(\sqrt{1-z^2}+1, \sqrt{y^2-z^2})} \,dx\,dz\,dy. \\ 
$$
The cylinder boundary intersects the cone boundary at $z = y\sqrt{1-y^2/4}$.  This means that $\sqrt{y^2-z^2} \le \sqrt{1-z^2}+1$ for $0\le z \le y\sqrt{1-y^2/4}$ and $\sqrt{1-z^2}+1 \le \sqrt{y^2-z^2}$ for $y\sqrt{1-y^2/4} \le z \le 1$, so we can write
$$
\int_0^1 z \left({\min(\sqrt{1-z^2}+1, \sqrt{y^2-z^2})} - 1\right) \, dz 
$$
as the sum
$$
  \int_0^{y\sqrt{1-y^2/4}} \left(z\sqrt{y^2-z^2} - z\right) \, dz + 
  \int_{y\sqrt{1-y^2/4}}^1 z\sqrt{1-z^2} \, dz.
$$
This sum of two integrals simplifies to 
$$
  -\frac{y^4}{8} + \frac{y^3}{3} - \frac{1}{3}.
$$
So
$$
  \begin{align}
  \int_{A_3} z/y^2 &= \int_{\sqrt{2}}^2 -\frac{y^2}{8} + \frac{y}{3} - \frac{1}{3y^2} \, dy  \\
  &= \frac{1}{6} - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{12}.
  \end{align}
$$

So the integral over the entire region $A$ is 
$$
  \left(\frac{1}{6}\right) + \left(\frac{5}{6} - \frac{7}{12}\sqrt{2}\right) + 
      \left(\frac{1}{6} - \frac{1}{12}\sqrt{2}\right) = 
      \frac{7}{6} - \frac{2}{3}\sqrt{2}.
$$